# C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a MFC program for the computer graphics
course. The class I declared is like this:

```
class CFace {
public:
    CFace();
    ~CFace();
    void SetFace(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);
    void Set(int a);
    int *vI;
};

CFace::CFace() {
    vI = NULL;
}

CFace::~CFace() {
    if (vI != NULL)
    {
        delete []vI;
        vI = NULL;
    }
}

void CFace::SetFace(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    vI = new int[5];
    vI[0] = a;
    vI[1] = b;
    vI[2] = c;
    vI[3] = d;
    vI[4] = e;
}
```

When I call
`SetFace()`
like this

```
void CDodecahedronDisplayView::ReadFace(CFace* F[12])
{
    F(0)->SetFace(0, 7, 8, 15, 4); // C2064
    F(1)->SetFace(6, 10, 9, 8, 7); // C2064
    F(2)->SetFace(1, 5, 6, 7, 0); // C2064
    /*other similar calls*/
}
```

I get the error

```
C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I omitted other similar calls. I should have written /*...*/ instead.

Comment: Okay... so "the error" happens. Now I have to figure out what "the error" means? Let me guess -- you are assuming that it is easier to have every reader backtrack to figure out where you mentioned the error, than for one person to copy the error to the spot where it is referenced? That view is surprisingly common, given that it's only easier for the one person most motivated to put in more work. ... I've put in the tremendous work of copy-pasting for you, but I suspect the error message is incomplete. Is there not some indication of a character within each line where the error occurs?

Comment: Thanks for ur work and huge patience for helping me modify my question, and it really helps me a lot because it's my first time raising a question here... The error was i wrongly used operator[] to access the F array, and it has been fixed. This is such a stupid mistake indeed. Thanks for your patience again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the elements in the `F` array you need `operator[]` and *not* `operator()`. I.e. your code should be

```cpp
F[0]->SetFace(...);
F[1]->SetFace(...);
F[2]->SetFace(...);
```